# Using animations on all javascript assignments

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, jquery-animate

I have a project that I am working on that makes many javascript dom html assignments, such as:

```
this.firstChild.nodeValue = "example";
document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = "example";
```

There is a large amount of them everywhere and not all of them are the same. I want it to be that whenever I assign a value/output to html it uses jquery animate "fade in."

Is this even possible to do without going through every assignment and doing it manually?

Thanks.

Comment: Are these DOM assignments user initiated, e.g., on click?

Comment: Some of them are triggered by user input, but others are triggered by an AI.

Comment: I don't see any way to do this without replacing all the assignments with a function that examines what is being assigned and then acts accordingly to give you a fade.  The only other thing I can think of is to replace all the relevant properties with `setter` functions, though I don't know if you can do that on native DOM objects in all browsers.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of, oh well, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't u try using function, passing arguments.

```
function animate(value, dom){
    dom.firstChild.nodeValue = value;
    document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = value;
    $(dom).fadeIn();
}
```

Comment: ...and than suddenly `$(dom)` :)